# Improve wording of Necromancer and Revival badges

Tags: feature-request, badges, wording

The descriptions of Necromancer and Revival badges are as follows:

> [Revival]     Answered more than 30 days later as first answer scoring 2 or more
>   [Necromancer] Answered a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more

I find the word "later" in both badge descriptions to be very clumsy and non-grammatical. I’d prefer the clearer, but slightly more verbose, “after it was asked”-

> [Revival]     Answered **a question** more than 30 days **after it was asked,** as first answer scoring 2 or more
>   [Necromancer] Answered a question more than 60 days **after it was asked,** with score of 5 or more

Comment: I don't think that's much clearer. "... after it was asked as first answer..."? "... after it was asked with score of 5 or more"?

Comment: @MichaelMyers: ok, i added a comma after "asked" to avoid that potential ambiguity

Comment: I was racking my brain trying to reword it completely, but you're right, that one comma makes it much better.

Comment: Quite.  I've just received the `Necromancer` badge, read the 'description' and had no idea what it meant.  'Later'?  Later than what?  'Answered'?  I answered someone else's question, or they answered mine?

Comment: `Answered a question more than 60 days after it was asked, with score of 5 or more`.  That's a definite improvement, but could I suggest `Answered a question with 5 or more votes, more than 60 days after it was asked`, assuming that's what it means.  To me `with a score of 5 or more` tagged on the end doesn't make it clear what that applies to.  And also, what is a 'score'?  Answered are 'voted' on, aren't they?  Or have I misunderstood what `Necromancer` means?

Comment: I'm curious as to why Revival was changed but Necromancer wasn't?