# Improve wording of Necromancer badge to specify answer score must be 5+

Tags: discussion, badges, wording

> Not a duplicate: [Improve wording of Necromancer and Revival badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69332/improve-wording-of-necromancer-and-revival-badges)

I read up on badges from time to time and I just now realized my understanding of [Necromancer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/17/necromancer) was completely backwards. The description says:

> **Necromancer** Answered a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

I thought this meant the *question* had to have a score of 5 or more, but I just saw someone awarded this badge for a question with a score of 1 and their answer was posted 2 years ago. Not only is the wording misleading ('question' being the immediate predicate to 'with a score' and 'answer' being used as a verb), but you then don't get the badge until the 5th upvote occurs, making the '60 days later' part of the description doubly confusing.

I would propose the following wording:

> Your answer to a 60+ day old question was upvoted 5 or more times.

Comment: The proposed formulation misses that the question must be 60 days old when answered, not when you get the 5th upvote.

Comment: I disagree, but I like Madara's proposed wording better anyways, so I'm not going to argue the point.

Comment: While we are at it, let's clarify the description of Populist badge as well

Answer (score 9):

I actually understood exactly what it meant from the beginning (It wouldn't make sense for the question to have +5 or more, What are you getting the badge for? Targeting a specific question, or for giving a great answer?)

However, if you got confused, there's no reason why others wouldn't. So I propose the following:

> Got a score of 5 or more on an answer posted 60 or more days after the question was asked.

The point is to describe what the badge is awarded for. It's not awarded for posting an answer (which the current wording implies), it's awarded for getting a high score for it (with the prior criteria or the question being old, and the answer being posted, met).

Comment: "What are you getting the badge for?" I had the exact same reaction when I read it and didn't think twice about it. Just a case of Brainnotworking syndrome, that day. I like your wording. New to meta, btw, who makes the decision/has the power to make the change?